# Why does UV light feel warm on my skin? Whereas infrared light heats up space around me plus my skin?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, thermal-radiation, biophysics, infrared-radiation

Noticed something weird today.

I have an infrared space heater that is pretty good at heating up my desk at work (as well as my skin obviously).

I also have a UV flashlight. I noticed the UV flashlight will make my skin feel warm when I shine it on my hand. But it's not heating up the air around it like the IR heater. It's just doing something to my skin to warm it up?

What's the physical explanation for this?

Is this why it feels good to be in the Sun?

Comment: I would be wary of shining your UV flashlight on any part of you body and in particular anywhere near your eyes.

Comment: If your UV flashlight is typical of what you can buy on Amazon, then it's emitter is one or several LEDs that consume a total of somewhere between one and ten Watts of electrical power. If your IR heater is typical of what you can buy in a department store to use for supplemental heat in your bedroom, then it probably uses more than a thousand Watts of electrical power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a spectrometer reading from both sources, it is hard to tell.

However, the industrial LED UV sources I have worked with put out plenty of IR (and visible) light; in fact, without continuous water cooling, the UV LED's would overheat and burn out. So if you had one of these shining on your skin, you would feel the heat coming from it.

Your heater radiates IR but it also *conducts* heat into the air which is in physical contact with the heating element inside it- which then sets *convection* into action. So the heater has heat transfer mechanisms that your flashlight does not have. This is why the air near the heater feels warm.

Answer (score 2):

You have to realize that this depends on the quantum nature of molecules in the air and on your skin.For the air and the skin to be heated, it means that the interaction of the electromagnetic waves on the molecules is probable enough so that the energy of the wave can be transferred to the molecules and raise the [temperature.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/kintem.html)  Temperature is measured, and it depends on  the velocity of particles.

It so happens that ultraviolet is a frequency that interacts with the molecules of your skin, but has **small interaction** with the molecules in the air. If the UV had high probability of interacting with the air molecules,there would be no ultraviolet left in the radiation from the sun outside, it would have been all absorbed in the air and contributing statistically to the  infrared temperature at the surface of earth.

> is this why it feels good to be in the Sun?

Yes, the direct infrared of the sun heat up the molecules on your skin.(which can be too much in the summer) . The direct ultraviolet  in the summer browns or burns the skin.

Comment: So it's IR not UV that makes us feel good in the Sun? 

"There would be no ultraviolet left in the radiation from the sun outside, it would have been all absorbed in the air and contributing statistically to the infrared temperature at the surface of earth." Not sure why the UV would be absorbed in the air if you just said it doesn't interact with the air?

Comment: What we register as pleasant heat in sun light , is mainly the infrared rays from the sun. The UV are local where they hit the the skin, and there will be some feeling of heat, You know that exposure to sunlight is also exposure to ultraviolet? It means theUV is  not absorbed by interacting with the atmospheric molecules .I have tried to make it clear