# Why does my UV LED flashlight feel warm on my skin while my IR flashlight does not?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, infrared-radiation

Both are 18 watts. Shouldn't IR feel warmer on my skin?

Comment: Aren't you saying both are 18 watts? The real question is why the IR would not feel the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/753908/2451

Comment: Even if both sources _emit_ the same total amount of power, the fraction of that power that will be _absorbed_ by your skin may depend on the wavelength. You only feel what your skin absorbs. [P.S., I would not directly expose my skin to that light. I know that the long-wave UV emitted by a typical "black light" (a.k.a., "wood's light") flashlight is a lot less harmful than shorter wavelengths such as you'd get from an electric arc lamp or a gas discharge lamp, but I wouldn't count on it to be completely harmless.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UV flashlight emits IR radiation as a byproduct of generating UV. So it will make your hand feel warm.

Regarding the IR flashlight, remember that 18 watts is what the flashlight *consumes*, not what it *radiates* (which will always be less than its consumption). Without any additional knowledge about the *spectrum* of light produced by each source, it isn't certain why the IR source isn't "warm enough" to heat your hand.

Comment: _Any_ electromagnetic radiation that is absorbed by your skin will feel warm. It doesn't have to be IR. We only associate warmth with IR because of our familarity with sources that (a) we encounter in our everyday lives, and (b) are powerful enough to give us a pleasent, toasty warm feeling, and (c) are safe to stand near without wearing personal protective equipment. Sources that meet (a), (b), and (c) tend to be black body sources with temperature in the high hundreds to low thousands of K—sources that emit most of their power as "longwave" IR.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, why not post this as an answer?